# Suggestion for algebraic topology books that will increase my visualization

Tags: algebraic-topology, book-recommendation, visualization

I am student of mathematics and I have started to learn algebraic topology . I want to learn visual things . Can you please suggest books that can help me to increase visualization ?

Comment: +1 to your posting for asking what I consider to be a profound question.  Personally, I have veered away from Topology precisely because my eidetic imagery abilities (i.e. ability to visualize) is very poor.  I have always assumed that this is a genetic condition (i.e. near the opposite of having a photographic memory).  However, it is not that implausible that the visualization requirements of Topology are relatively narrow and that therefore, relevant positive strides can be *learned*.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1146623/visualising-algebraic-topology

Answer (score 0):

I think on a first pass Hatcher's pictures can be difficult to visualize despite it being a fairly geometric text.

I recommend Kinsey's ["Topology of Surfaces"](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/kinsey.pdf).

Comment: If you need harder algebraic topology lmk what particular subjects you are trying to visualize